# Insert string after images on content

Tags: php, regex

i have a string as

```
<p>content</p>
<p><img src="1.jpg" alt="alt image 1"></p>
<p>other content</p>
<p><img src="2.jpg" alt="alt image 2"></p>
```

i want to get alt images and insert after image, like

```
<p>content</p>
<p><img src="1.jpg" alt="alt image 1"></p><p>alt image 1</p>
<p>other content</p>
<p><img src="2.jpg" alt="alt image 2"></p><p>alt image 2</p>
```

i know get alt by

```
preg_match_all("/< *img[^>]*alt *= *[\"\']?([^\"\']*)/i",$str,$alt);
foreach ($alt[1] as $alti) {
$altimg[]=$alti;
}
```

and i was try this code

```
for($i=0;$i < count($alt[1] );$i++){
    $regex = '#<img.+?src="([^"]*)".*?/?>#i';
    $replace = '$0<div>'.$altimg[$i].'</div>';
}
$str = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $str);
```

but the result show

```
<p>content</p>
<p><img src="1.jpg" alt="alt image 1"></p><p>alt image 2</p>
<p>other content</p>
<p><img src="2.jpg" alt="alt image 2"></p><p>alt image 2</p>
```

please tell me how to fix this, thank for your help and Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: [Almost but not quite](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7Hhgo8)

Answer (score 1):

This can solves problem:

```
$regex = '#<img.+?src="([^"]*)".*?alt *= *[\"\']?([^\"\']*)[\"\']?.*?/?>#i';
$replace = '$0<p>$2</p>';
$str = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in two ways:

1. Easy client-side way:

   ```
   $("img").closest("p").after("<p>Content</p>");
   ```
2. Tough PHP Way using [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/):

   ```
   $html = '';
   foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
      echo $element->src . '<br>';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
$str = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $str);
```

is outside of the loop and will be running with the last value of $regex & $replace after exiting the for loop, hence it's inserting the last found alt.

Comment: Thanks flauntster, so how to fix it?